# Is there a way to use/get the value from a current entry window

Tags: loops, tkinter, multiple-instances, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to get the variable that's entered in an entry widget on the Return key pressed event, but struggling a bit. What I have tried has always produced a blank result.
This code may look messy and hap-hazard, but it's only going to be a template that I'll be using on a current project!

I've tried that many things to get it to work, I can't remember what I have tried!

```
from collections import OrderedDict
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


labelLIST = OrderedDict([
                        ('Temp ID', 'tempID'),
                        ('PO Number', "poNumber"),
                        ('Reference', "reference"),
                        ('Cut/Sample Date', "csDate"),
                        ('Cut Number', "cut")
                        ])

i = 0
e_loops = len(labelLIST)
print (e_loops)


def bval1(event=None):
    for i in range(e_loops):
        print (entries[i].get())
    entries[0].delete(0, tk.END)
    entries[0].insert(0, 'DISABLED')
    entries[0].configure(state='disabled')


def bval2():
    entries[0].configure(state='normal')
    for i in range(e_loops):
        entries[i].delete(0, tk.END)
    entries[0].focus()


def onClick(event):
    ent = event.widget  # event.widget is the widget that called the event
    print(ent.cget("text"))  # Print the text for the selected button
    event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()


def enterEV(event):
    # print(entries[].get())
    event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()

entries = []
for key, value in labelLIST.items():
    label = tk.Label(root, text=key)
    label.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=1, pady=1)
    entry = tk.Entry(root, width=10)
    entry.grid(row=i, column=1, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
    if value == "cut":
        entry.bind('<Return>', bval1)
    else:
        # entry.bind('<Return>', enterEV)
        entry.bind('<Return>', onClick)
    entries.append(entry)
    i = i+1

button = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=bval1)
button.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=9, sticky="ew")

button = tk.Button(root, text="Clear", command=bval2)
button.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=9, sticky="ew")

entries[0].focus()

tk.mainloop()
```

When enter/return is pressed, I want the value that is the entry box to be  printed to terminal via the onClick event. But the output is always empty.

```
def onClick(event):
    ent = event.widget  # event.widget is the widget that called the event
    print(ent.cget("text"))  # Print the text for the selected button
    event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the `text` attribute to get the value in an `Entry` widget. Using `cget("text")` returns the value for the `textvariable` attribute. Since you haven't set that attribute, it will always be the empty string.

Instead, you need to call the `get` method:

```
print(ent.get())
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I can't believe it was something as simple as that!!